# Performance penalty for jQuery's live() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

For certain elements, whenever hovering over them I want the elements to get larger and then shrink back down when unhovering.  So I simply use `$('.elementClass').hover(function() { enlarge(this); }, function() { shrink(this); });`.  I put this in the `$(function() { });` area of all webpages as many webpages have these kinds of elements.

Sometimes I need to create new dynamic elements and they have these elements above.  Of course, I have to call the above hover function again for them because they didn't exist at first.

What seems to be most convenient is to simply have a whole battery of `$('.variousClasses').live('variousEvents', function() { });` calls in every webpage for all possible functionality like the above.

So the question is if there's a performance penalty for calling `live()` so many times even on elements that won't ever fire those events or elements which will never exist?  Is it important that I be careful about only calling `hover()` or `live('hover')` (and other events) **only** when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general answer to your question, you should attempt to minimize extraneous function calls--maybe more so in a dynamic content situation.

In particular, `live()` is a good example to use for this question because it does carry with it some (potentially) significant performance complications. When you call `live()`, jQuery binds the event you have selected to the `document` object. This means that every time the event is fired, it bubbles up from the origin element to the `document` object. Depending on your site structure (and just in general), this can be costly.

### A much better alternative with `delegate()`

It's better to use jQuery's `delegate()` function, especially if you have a pre-defined parent container element that all of your events will be firing within. When you use `delegate()`, you're basically using a restricted version of `live()` such that the event only propagates to the specified parent element. As a result, you avoid many potentially costly event fires on elements you do not care about.

In your case, since you are working with dynamically generated content, you either have to use the aforementioned functions or setup your code such that when the element is inserted into the DOM, it also binds the event handler to it. The former is likely easier, but the latter could offer marginally (likely indiscernible) better performance.